# Implements exceptions on Java Digital Clock

Tags: java

i try to develop digital clock using java. i still new in java. the problem is, i try to implement exception on my code but i did not know how to make it.

my make code as below

Main Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class DigitalClock extends JFrame {

JLabel jLabClock;
ClockThread ct;

public DigitalClock(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Digital Clock");
    jLabClock = new JLabel("00:00:00 AM");
    f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jLabClock.setFont(new Font("DS-Digital", Font.BOLD, 50));
    jLabClock.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(15, 245, 15));
    f.add(jLabClock);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ct = new ClockThread(this);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    DigitalClock digitalClock = new DigitalClock();
}
}
```

Thread Class

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;



public class ClockThread extends Thread{

DigitalClock dc;
int timeRun = 0;

public ClockThread(DigitalClock dc){

    this.dc = dc;
    start();
}

@Override
public void run(){

    while(timeRun == 0){

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int am_pm = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

        String day_night = "";

        if (am_pm == 1){
            day_night = "PM";
        }
        else{
            day_night = "AM";
        }
        String time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + day_night;

        dc.jLabClock.setText(time);
    }

}
}
```

this code work fine to me but i just want to try use exception on my code. can somebody help me, please

Comment: Exceptions are used when something could go wrong and to handle that. What could go wrong with your code?

Comment: i know my code is fine and nothing wrong but i like to try using exception on my code. if possible i want to put something like try-catch method. and i did't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to introduce exception handling in your code is by throwing `IllegalArgumentException` in your `ClockThread` constructor when the `DigitalClock` object is null - something like this:

```
public ClockThread(DigitalClock dc){
    if(dc == null){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Digital Clock cannot be Null. Initialize the Digital Clock Object first.");
    }
   //code reachable if no exception
    this.dc = dc;
    start();
}
```

I hope this gives you some ideas. Please try it out and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Most Java gurus advise that `NullPointerException` be thrown if a required value is `null` so I'd recommend throwing that instead of `IllegalArgumentException`. (The newest Java core classes follow this pattern.)

Comment: Good point. Throwing a NullPointerException would be better in my example - it was just an example - but I agree with you completely.

Comment: thank you, this really help me

Comment: Good to know this helps - please accept the answer if you find it useful so that your question can be marked as answered. Enjoy.